# Css color set confused

Tags: css, colors

I posted before but it still doesn't work, please help me.
so the original color is yellow. I want it to be white so I set css #fff !important.
hover is red easy. but I want the only 1 link is that is clicked turn purple. 
It means, at first, it all white, hover red, but only 1 link (page) I currently select turns purple. Please help, I try to use visited but all turns purple instead of 1.

```
          <div class="naomi">
          <ul>
              <li ><a class="link1" style="color:yellow" href="#1">Link1</a>more text </li>
               <li ><a class="link2" style="color:yellow" href="#2">Link2</a> more text </li>
               <li ><a class="link3" style="color:yellow" href="#3">Link3</a> more text </li>
         </ul>
       </div>
```

css in link

https://jsfiddle.net/csh7nuc1/

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the style for visited links too: `a:visited`
see fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/csh7nuc1/4/

Answer (score 1):

Use **:focus** instead of **active** and **visited**.

Comment: :focus is actually different than :visited

Comment: Yah. its totally different i agree with you.

Comment: Sorry, I see now that wasn't what @pexichdu was after

Comment: well I  used focus  and it works as I expected here https://jsfiddle.net/csh7nuc1/4/ but it still doesn't work on my wordpress menu although I did exactly here, i focus purple but it turns back white right away, maybe it has something to do with the !important, is there a way to overprioritize !important?

Comment: theres no way you can overprioritize the !important.

Comment: Best to avoid the use of !important unless you really have to. See if there is an overriding style in the rest of your css or any other css used by plugins etc. You can use the inspector to see what the issue is most likely.

Comment: Also remove the your inline style that makes the text default color yellow to avoid using of !important in color changing.